# Can I send back a function reference as a response to an api request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sockets

Can I send back a function reference or function as such as a response to api call from an express server and the front-end framework is angular js?

I tried to send the response object like: `{per: true, listEvnts: events}`
where `events` is a function, but in my client side I only get an object with 
one key: `{per: true}`. The second key is missing.

The desired output would be a response object containing both keys, like: `{per: true, listEvents: events}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot send functions over HTTP. Functions are specific to the program they are a part of. You cannot send that over a network. You can't even serialise the function into JSON, since JSON doesn't specify a "function" type.

You'd have to send the source code of the function as string and then `eval` that source code into an actual function on the client, but that's a bad idea. You don't necessarily know the client, and any code you send isn't guaranteed to be executable on that client in that specific context.

Send data, not code.

Answer (score -1):

No this is not possible. If you want to call function from client to server you can create RPC kind of structure. Please provide the details what exactly your requirement here, So can help you better.

{per: true, listEvnts: events} is simple json string, misssing of "events" may have some other reason more detail about your requirement and current object will help to understand query.